# order by in UNION clauses existing a view in left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to order the results by one attribute: Series (for each table). There is also a view in the queries... 
The original query is:

```
    select zz.Id
          ,t1.Series
          ,t1.SeriesType
    from table 1 t1 
    inner join another_table (...)
    left join view (...)

    UNION

    select zz.Id
          ,t2.Series
          ,t2.SeriesType
    from table 2 t2
    inner join another_table (...)
    left join view (...)

    UNION

    select zz.Id
          ,t3.Series
          ,t3.SeriesType
    from table 3 t3 
    inner join another_table (...)
    left join view (...) 

    order zz.Id
```

this **works**, but only gives the order for zz.Id. How to achieve order for the Series column for each table?

I have tried with:

```
select *
from
    (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT zz.Id
          ,t1.Series
          ,t1.SeriesType
    from table 1 t1 
    inner join another_table (...)
    left join view (...)
    order by t1.Series) as table1

    UNION
select *
from
    (    
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT zz.Id
          ,t2.Series
          ,t2.SeriesType
    from table 2 t2
    inner join another_table (...)
    left join view (...)
    order by t2.Series) as table2

    UNION

select *
from
    (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT zz.Id
          ,t3.Series
          ,t3.SeriesType
    from table 3 t3 
    inner join another_table (...)
    left join view (...)
    order by t3.Series) as table3
```

.

all tables are connected by one single table and this zz.id is unique for table1, table2, table3. (I see it is not possible to sort out at same time Id and series. so I will only sort out the series by each type of series). Thanks.

for example table 1 is:

```
zz.Id     t1.series      SERIES_Type
---------------------------------
1         4545              1
2         5655              1
3         2344              1
```

table 2

```
zz.Id     t2.series   SERIES_Type
---------------------------------
4         4546            2
```

table 3

```
zz.Id     t3.series    SERIES_Type
--------------------------------
5         545             3   
6         343             3
7         2344            3
```

final result should be:

```
zz.Id       series    SERIES_Type
--------------------------------
3             2344       1
1             4545       1
2             5655       1
4             4546       2     
6             343        3
5             545        3
7             2344       3
```

Comment: What is your expected output here?  Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: The sub-query's ORDER BY clauses make no difference. The final one at the end is the one that is used.

Comment: @JNevill You don't have to delete, but let's find out what output the OP actually wants here.

Comment: Without seeing an example of what you are trying to achieve, I have no idea what you're asking.   This sentence "How to achieve order for the Series column for each table?" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: what's your error - It might actually disallow sorting in a sub-query.  Do you want to sort on series, then ID?  You seem to say 'this works except...' then 'it is not working at all .' so I'm confused as to how close you are

Comment: thanks for all inputs. I have managed to solve it. It is impossible to sort out the zz.id and the series. It should to be to sort out by series type and then series. and in this way it is very simple indeed. Order by series_type, series in the final gives what is desired. I will delete this post...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried two keys in the `order by`?

```
order Id, SeriestType
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your "expected result" all you need is:

```
order by SeriesType, Series
```

Am I correct or misunderstood...

Comment: You are right. I have written it after the comments of several collaborators. chech above :) . Many thanks, PawelCz for confirmation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it occurs to you to use "top 100 percent" - stop coding. This does nothing useful EVER. A resultset (which is the only way to look at rows) has no reliable or defined order unless the query that generated it included an order by clause. If you want to order rows according to each query within the union, then you need to add a column to each query that you can include in the final sort by clause.

As an example, this adds a column named srt (because "sort" is a reserved word - pick a name meaningful to you). Each participating query in the union is assigned a value that can be used to identify the "group". Again - make it meaningful to you. That column is included in the final sort by clause as the first column and will "group" rows.

```
use tempdb;
go

declare @tbl table (id int not null, series varchar(10) not null, seriestype varchar(10) not null); 
insert @tbl(id, series, seriestype) values (1, '4521', 1), (1, '3011', 1), (2, '9999', 2), (3, '0000', 1), (3, '1111', 1);

select id, series, seriestype, 1 as srt from @tbl where id = 1 
union all
select id, series, seriestype, 2 as srt from @tbl where id = 2
union all 
select id, series, seriestype, 3 as srt from @tbl where id = 3 
order by srt, id, series;
```

Now that you have updated your post, it seems you might be able to sort by seriestype. But that might be accidental due to your query logic and the data that exists in your tables. Only you can know if that is correct. TBH, I find the use of a union (vis-a-vis your sample output) suspicious.

And one final note. If you do not want to see the srt column in the final resultset, that can be arranged.

Comment: thanks for the tip! Nevertheless I have seen here in SO several cases of people using TOP 100 Percent especially when a view is present in the SQL code. So to prevent it, if I stumble upon with such issue I'll use your approach.

Comment: The use of "top 100 percent" in a view is simply an issue with a GUI that is trying to prevent illegal syntax and users who do not understand that a view (like a table) has no defined or predictable order. They avoid the "can't order a view" error by including the top directive - which only avoids the error and does nothing useful by definition (though testing using small datasets on lightly loaded machines might suggest an order).